# Add ACF Gallery Image Titles to Search

Tags: php, wordpress, gallery, advanced-custom-fields

Is there a way to alter the functions.php file so it allows people to search based on an image title, caption, alt text or description, and receive the related result (image) from the ACF Gallery?

Example: I have a hardwood company website, if the user searches for ‘Red Oak’, return all product images that contain the image title ‘Red Oak’.

Thanks in advance!